# Finding the Length of a Line Parallel to a side of a Triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If one side of a triangle has a length of $64$. A line segment of length $k$ is parallel to that side of the triangle and has endpoints on the other two sides of the triangle. The ratio of the triangular region to the area of the quadrilateral region is $9:247$. How can I find the value of $k$?

I was thinking of setting up a proportion of $9/256$ equal to something but I was unsure what that something should be.

I know the answer should be $k=12$

Comment: To clarify, is the side with length $64$ the hypotenuse? Is this a right triangle?

Comment: I retyped the problem exactly how I found it. Did not mention being a right triangle unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter anyway. See my answer for details. I was only asking because your title is rather unclear then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say, instead of envisioning a triangular area to a quadrilateral area, we can look at the small triangle to the big triangle, as you suggested. There, we get $9/256$.

The key to solving from here is that $(\frac{length_1}{length_2})^2 = \frac{Area_1}{Area_2}$.

We know our ratio for $\frac{Area_1}{Area_2}$, and the hypotenuse/larger length $length_2$ is given, so we can solve for our other variable.

The idea behind the equation is rather simple intuitively. Imagine we have two similar squares, one of length $6$ and another of length $8$. If we were to find the ratio (larger/smaller), it would be $4/3$. Notice how nearly all expressions to find area end up squaring the side length ($\pi r^2, s^2, \frac{s^2\sqrt3}{4}$, etc.) Multiplying our sides, we get that the areas are $36$ and $64$, for which the ratio is $16/9$. Practically, $\frac{Area_1}{Area_2} = (\frac{(length_1)^2}{(length_2)^2}) = (\frac{length_1}{length_2})^2$

Comment: Where does the (length_1 / length_2)^2 come from?

Comment: I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Excellent. Thank You.